Confusion about claim on truth functions (Elliot Mendelson, Introduction to Mathematical Logic)
A truth function of $n$-arguments is defined to be a function of $n$- arguments, the arguments and values of which are the truth values T or F. As we have seen, any statement form containing n distinct statement letters determines a corresponding truth function of n arguments.
He then futher elaborates,

To be precise, enumerate all statement letters as follows: $A, B, …, Z;$
$A_1, B_1, …, Z_1; A_2, …,.$ If a statement form contains the $i_{th_1},...,i_{th_n}$
statement letters in this enumeration, where $i_1 < ⋯ < i_n$, then
the corresponding truth function is to have $x_{i_1},…,x_{i_n}$ in
that order, as its arguments, where $x_{i_j}$ corresponds to the $i_{jth}$
statement letter.

My Questions:

the arguments and values of which are the truth values T or F

1.) The author has not (rigorously) defined an argument at this point in the book, so already I'm confused, but is he just claiming that the individual arguments that make up the $n$ arguments are either true or false?

If a statement form contains the $i_{th_1},...,i_{th_n}$  statement
letters in this enumeration, where $i_1 < ⋯<i_n$

2.) I'm not confident about what is being denoted here. I had originally assumed $$i_{th_j}\in\{A_j,B_j,...,Z_j\}$$
but $i_1 < ⋯<i_n$ being ordered puzzles me

In general if someone  could break the paragraph down for me that would greatly be appreciated. Thanks.

Please don't rely on the title of your MSE questions for important information (like the name of a text you are asking about): the body of your question should be self-contained.There is a fairly rigorous definition of the arguments of a function in the introduction to Mendelson's book. Mendelson isn't making a "claim" here, he's making a definition. He actually writes 1ℎ,2ℎ... and not what you wrote. What he means is that the propositional function defined by a propositional statement has as its argument list the variables that appear in the statement ...

... and they are listed in the order they appear in the list $A, B, \ldots$.  I agree that his notation is very confusing. A verbal explanation would have been much easier to understand. (I have just deleted an earlier comment, where I got the ordering the wrong way round.) His examples do clarify this.

As I can understand from the OP's description, the confusion here is terminological. I shall present an explanation accordingly; otherwise, I suppose, the question is better revised.
There is another question similar to this one (see Why is the 'argument' of a function named as such?); however, it might be better to record here a rather detailed answer for future reference.
The semantic history of the word argument is rooted in Latin and its meaning has been enriched over centuries. Let us note its etymological explanation from Online Etymology Dictionary:

early 14c., "statements and reasoning in support of a proposition or
causing belief in a doubtful matter," from Old French arguement
"reasoning, opinion; accusation, charge" (13c.), from Latin argumentum
"a logical argument; evidence, ground, support, proof," from arguere
"make clear, make known, prove". The sense in English passed through
"subject of contention" (1590s) to "a quarrel" (by 1911), a sense
formerly attached to argumentation.

In Medieval Scholastic philosophy, argumentum evolved to signify a structured line of reasoning or debate. Thus, in rhetoric, an argument became an organised set of statements (premisses) that supports a conclusion, a foundational concept in philosophical discussions. This idea was later expanded to mathematical usage, where mathematical proofs and the logical steps within them were viewed as arguments supporting the truth of a theorem.
By the 17th century, as mathematical functions became more formally defined, argument was adopted to mean the input of a function (i.e., the independent value supplied to determine the function's result). The dependent nature of function’s output on this input was taken to resemble the dependence of a logical conclusion on its premisses.
Hence, we have two distinct senses of the term argument in logic; roughly to state, one is inherited from rhetoric, and the other is from mathematics.
In the given context, Mendelson uses it in mathematical sense, that is, an independent variable of the truth function.
